# Streaming any image to HTML client?

Tags: java, image, servlets, streaming, gif

The use case is to reference an image URL (e.g. <img src=...>) in an HTML document which would be viewed by a browser or an email client, and have the image reflect the current state as determined by the server. The image would be dynamically computed and created by the back-end, e.g. a servlet, at regular intervals, e.g. every minute. It's kind of like a video-feed, but with a very poor frame rate (one frame per minute). ;)

I guess there are at least two key assumptions that must be satisfied here:

1. The back-end producing the image must be able to send the initial version of the image, then subsequent versions of the image, e.g. in a compute-send-sleep loop, without the client closing the connection. The back-end would keep the HTTP connection to the client open and keep sending new versions until the client closes the connection, e.g. because it's no longer displaying the document.
2. The client fetching the image will detect that the back-end keeps sending new versions of the image and redraw it. I'm not sure if the server can explicitly signal this to the client, e.g. set a keep-alive response header or something to that effect -- or perhaps it's not even needed give that the server will keep the connection open.

Are these assumptions reasonable? For the back-end I'll use a servlet as proof of concept, while the front-end will be a browser like Firefox and an email client like Thunderbird.

I'm not quite sure how the server would signal the client that the previous image is obsolete and can be discarded and the new one should be received and redrawn, but perhaps it's simply a matter of flushing and resending the new data? Any pointers on that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Using something like an animated gif won't work as I won't be able to know ahead of time what the image will be. In other words, I can't pre-compute the sequence of images and send it once.

Comment: So you want to edit the recipients' email, after they have received it, by changing the content of a hotlinked image? I've never heard of this technique being used. I'd recommend just giving them a link, and they can see the statistics there, which should be rendered in HTML.

Comment: @Ermir, the HTML document itself (e.g. the email, web page) is not edited/changed per-se, but the image referenced in the HTML might be constantly changing (like an animated GIF, except it's not static data, but rather dynamic). The HTML document and the referenced image would be two different URLs. But yes, what the user would see would be "edited" in a way, i.e. change when the image changes. The problem I'm trying to solve is that of avoiding to refresh the document (e.g. page/email) to get the current image. -Kaare

Comment: You need to use Javascript if you want content to change without refreshing, and since there is no Javascript in HTML emails, what you are trying to do will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging I stumbled across the mixed-replace content type, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Mixed-Replace. Please note that the support for this does not seem to be 100% according to the Wikipedia entry -- I don't have Internet Explorer or Outlook so I'm unable to test, but it does work for current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Thunderbird.

Steps:

1. Send "Content-type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=<SOME_BOUNDARY_STRING>" to the client.
2. For each image being sent do:

   a) send "Content-type: <MIME_TYPE>" e.g. "image/png".

   b) send the image as raw bytes.

   c) send the boundary like "--<SOME_BOUNDARY_STRING>" -- note the double-hyphens.

   d) flush.
3. Wait whatever interval and repeat. The connection will be closed by the client or the server can close it.

Yes, this is pretty heavy on the server. If you need to get an image for multiple URLs for a web page, it might be better to poll as opposed to stream. However, in my case, the key benefit is to avoid stale images in emails and the use case calls for a single image, which is far less heavy on the server. You can add parameters to the URL to control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is it essential for the server to send the image to the browser instead of browser polling for the image?

generally clients poll the server for updates since it lowers the load on the server. Maybe you can design it like that.

I have never tried it myself but with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) you should be able to create a socket which the server can then send images to. Not sure how easy this is going to be though.

polling the server would be the simplest option though

Comment: @"Osama Javed", I could work around it for the browser part as I could have it poll the server. However, I'm not sure that would do it for the email client, though. I'll see if there's a way to have the email client refresh the page using a redirect loop or maybe even JavaScript, but I strongly prefer a server-centric solution as it would keep the logic on the server and I'd avoid potential old logic in old emails.

Comment: @kaared in that case node.js is the only thing I know of that allows server to client communication. but even that might not work in email clients either. good luck with your project